# Hiding the file path of a programming computer from hexdigit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, decompiling, file-structure

I programmed a C# program for my friend and when he got it, he opened it with hexedit and was able to see the filepath to the debugging folder on my computer saved on the program. I gave him the exe that was compiled in the debugging folder. Is there anyway to hide the file structure of your programming computer from decompiling software in Visual Studios?

Note: I am not sure if this applies to files that are created when you "publish." I do not want the user to install a program, it is just a 1-file exe that does not need to be installed. I need an answer that does not involve publishing the project.

Comment: Why aren't you compiling in Release mode when you distribute your application? Debug mode is for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the release configuration instead of debug, and set Debug Info to None in your project settings. See these articles for more information:

- [How to: Set Debug and Release Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx)
- [/debug (C# Compiler Options)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cw0bt21.aspx)

Comment: Now the filestructure that it points to refers to my pdb file inside my release folder, not much better than the one in the debug folder.

Comment: @DazSlayer: Did you change Debug Info to None? That should eliminate the PDB entirely.